# Android - Display custom dialog from another custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I have an activity which pops up a custom dialog.

On that dialog I have a few buttons. I need one of these buttons to display another custom dialog when the user clicks it (I want to open a new listview for the user to select from).

When I`ve tried to so I get an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Is there a way to do what I need?

10x :)

Comment: create an layout which should have all the views you want in the layout. add this layout into an activity.
in activity declaration in manifest add this tag 

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"

and when you are calling showDialo(int) call startActivty instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use activities, Activity A has the popup dialog which is Activity B, Activity B has the popup dialog which in Activity C.

Just add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to your activity tag in the manifest for activities B and C

```
    <activity android:name=".Classname"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.CLASSNAME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Just change classname to the name of the class you made

Comment: create another class, and then add that line i posted when you add it to the AndroidManifest file. It'll look like a dialog but act like a normal activity